# Why does the cursor not work in VR mode on Android in Google Chrome in version 1.0.3?

Tags: aframe

The cursor does not work in VR mode on Android in Google Chrome in version 1.0.3. Stands in one place. In version 1.0.1, this worked.
Took from an example:

```
<a-entity camera look-controls>
  <a-entity cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 500"
            position="0 0 -1"
            geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.02; radiusOuter: 0.03"
            material="color: black; shader: flat">
  </a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

Comment: Check to make sure that you have permission to access the browser's motion & orientation permissions. It's at least disabled for iOS by default and Chrome may have followed. A-Frame's cursor example works on the latest Chrome on Android for me: https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/test/cursor/

Comment: All permissions are there. This works for me on version 1.0.1. Does not work on version 1.0.3 in VR mode!!! Switch to VR mode and see that even the example you sent doesn't work on your phone either.

Comment: I remove the question. Fixed in version 1.0.4